# Redirect Item To Fallback

Tags: language-fallback, redirect

I am doing internal redirects. I need to have the target item point back to fallback if no current language is available. Any insights here?

```
LinkField TOURL = RedirectItem.Fields["To url"];
Item ToUrl = null;
if (TOURL != null)
{
    if (TOURL.TargetItem.IsFallback && (TOURL.IsInternal || TOURL.IsMediaLink) && TOURL.TargetItem != null)
    {
        ToUrl = TOURL.TargetItem; <-- "How can I get this target item to see its fallback?"
    } 
    else if ((TOURL.IsInternal || TOURL.IsMediaLink) && TOURL.TargetItem != null)
    {
        ToUrl = TOURL.TargetItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the item in the original language:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(TOURL.TargetID, TOURL.TargetItem.OriginalLanguage)
```

> OriginalLanguage is a property that returns the original language for
>   the current item. If the item is not a fallback item, it returns the
>   item.Language.

You can still check if it is an actual fallback item before doing this call by using is the `IsFallback` property you already have in the code.

```
var targetItem = TOURL.TargetItem;
if ((TOURL.IsInternal || TOURL.IsMediaLink) && targetItem != null)
{
    ToUrl = targetItem.IsFallback ? Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(TOURL.TargetID, targetItem.OriginalLanguage) : targetItem;
}
```

ps: you might want to change the names "TOURL" and "ToUrl" as well ;)